# How to take the Fourier transform of this distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, brownian-motion, distribution-theory

I am following the recent paper from Mourat and Weber ([GLOBAL WELL-POSEDNESS OF THE DYNAMIC $\Phi^4_3$ MODEL ON THE TORUS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01234.pdf))  where we find the following:

[image]

Where the strange $i$-like symbol is defined as:

[image]

and $\xi$ is the space time white noise that we constructed as:

[image]

I couldn't derive relation (4.1)

**Attempt:**

The Fourier transform of a distribution is an extension of the ordinary Fourier transform for $L^1$ functions:
$$ \hat i(t,\omega) = \int i(t)(x) e^{-2\pi i w\cdot x} \, dx $$

but $i(t)$ is a distribution, therefore

$$ \hat i(t,\omega) = i(t)( \psi_\omega) $$

where $\psi_\omega(x) = e^{-2\pi i w\cdot x}$
now, since $i(t)$ has an integral form

$$\hat i(t,\omega) = \big(\int_{-\infty}^t P_{t-s}(\xi(s))\, ds\big)( \psi_\omega) \\
=\int_{-\infty}^t P_{t-s}(\xi(s)( \psi_\omega))\, ds
$$

but $$\xi(s)( \psi_{\omega}) = \sum_{\omega'} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\psi_{\omega}} (t,\omega') dW(t,\omega')  = ? $$

How should we proceed to obtain (4.1)?

**trying a bit further:**

Since $(\psi_\omega)_{\omega \in \Bbb{Z}^d}$ is an orthonomal set in the Thorus, one might reasonably write:

$$\xi(s)( \psi_{\omega}) = \sum_{\omega'} \int \hat{\psi_{\omega}} (t,\omega') dW(t,\omega')  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dW(t,\omega) =? $$

It may make more sense to write

$$\hat i(t,\omega) = \big(\int_{-\infty}^t P_{t-s}(\xi(s))\, ds\big)( \psi_\omega) \\
=\int_{s= -\infty}^t P_{t-s}(\xi(s))( \psi_\omega)\, ds\\
=\int_{s = -\infty}^t \sum_{\omega'} \int_{t = -\infty}^\infty \hat{P_{t-s}\psi_{\omega}} (t,\omega') dW(t,\omega') ds
\overset{?}{=}\int_{s = -\infty}^t \hat{P}_{t-s}(\omega) dW(s,\omega)\\
$$